# Unity3d components

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I started to learn how to create 2D games with the Unity3D engine. I found two plugins: [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) and [2D Toolkit](http://www.unikronsoftware.com/2dtoolkit/).

My problem is that these plugins have duplicate functionality, both work with sprites, animation, etc. I can't work out which is better to use to create 2D game.

Comment: Everyone uses 2DToolkit.  BUT be aware that since this question appeared,  Unity now includes Unity 2D as standard.  In any event this question should be closed as it's just "software recommendation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do some research to answer your question. One of the main problems in making 2D games with Unity (using sprites) are performances issues.

It is common have performance problems with free alternatives like the free version of Orthello or the 1st version of Sprite Manager. 
I never used 2D toolkit, but I believe that unity community has a lot of users who has purchased a 2D toolkit license and you can find help in their foruns and comparisons with other 2D tools like ex2D and etc.

I recommend you to read these (good) tutorials

http://www.rocket5studios.com/tutorials/make-a-2d-game-in-unity3d-using-only-free-tools-part-1/

http://blogs.unity3d.com/2013/05/17/a-good-workflow-to-smoothly-import-2d-content-into-unity-part-i-authoring-and-exporting/

The second one was posted in the unity official blog and I believe that you can solve some of your doubts there.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally just use the built in 4.6 UI and 2D tools now. NGUI may have a few additional features currently. But the built in UI and 2D tools are official meaning they will be indefinitely improved and supported as long as Unity exists, and probably with much greater funding than any alternative. Thus the knowledge set developed from using the built in tools will have greater longevity, and will ultimately surpass all other options.

Answer (score 0):

**NGUI** is definitely the best system in the Asset Store for making your User interface. 
For a sprites in 2D game i would recommend using build in **Unity Sprite renderers**. They are mega fast.

Answer (score -1):

Ngui as the name suggests is more suitable for GUI and HUD, even though it has an animation components. There is actually a third option which I am using for my 2d games: NGUi for menus + HUD since its using its own camera and vertical planes with very naive sprite animation script for 2d animations, its quite enough for 2d needs. Try searching for Unity 2d animation tutorials there are a lot of these on the internet.

Comment: UI system and 2D Toolkit are totally different thing. Only common thing is they both rendering in 2d space.